# create table and show of selected fields

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I filled in a form, and entered the number of axles (The black circles). Then the forms sends me to this page:

[image: Form added]

In this form I entered 12 axles, and it shows them here.
Now under the black circles you see text boxes. Ignore those. But under them you see check boxes.
Now what I want with those is the folowing:

When I select for example 2 of them, and press: Make Boogie. I want it to create a table, and show content like this:

[image: example]

Now, when I have pressed Make Boogie. I want those 2 option boxes (Or more depending on wich you selected) To gray out. so I can't select them anymore.
Now, when I press the next 2 or 3 axles, and select: Make Boogie. I want the table to expand and show that information aswell. And gray out the select option after it is done.

My code (if needed):

```
<div id="center">
<?php
    //Train is send here//
    $add_train = $database->train_add();
?>
    Train: <?php echo $_POST['train_name']; ?>
    <!--Here we make the number of fields based on the number of axles-->
    <div id="axle_bogie_border"><br /> <br />
    <!--The show axles are the number of checkboxes (Filled in by a user)-->
        <table>
            <div id="show_axles">
                <tr>
                    <?php
                        $_POST['number_of_axles'];
                            if(isset($_POST['number_of_axles'])){
                            for($i=0; $i<$_POST['number_of_axles']; $i++){
                                echo "<td>" . "<div id='axle_figure'>" . $i . "</div>" . "</td>";
                            }   
                        }
                    ?>
                </tr>               
            </div>


            <div id="distances">
                <tr>
                    <?php
                        $_POST['number_of_axles'];
                            if(isset($_POST['number_of_axles'])){
                            for($i=0; $i<$_POST['number_of_axles']; $i++){
                                echo "<td>" . "<input type='text' placeholder='Distance $i' id='field' name='distance[$i]'>" . "</td>";
                            }
                        }
                    ?>
                </tr>
            </div>


            <div id="checkboxes">
                <tr>
                    <?php
                        $_POST['number_of_axles'];
                            if(isset($_POST['number_of_axles'])){
                            for($i=0; $i<$_POST['number_of_axles']; $i++){
                                echo "<td>" . "<input type='checkbox' name='box[$i]'>" . "</td>";
                            }
                        }
                    ?>
                </tr>
            </div>
        </table>


            <!--De onClick function is nog een test (zie Script bij lijn 77)-->
            <button onclick="myFunction();" id="add_train_button2">Refresh</button>
            <button onclick="myFunction('testing');" id="add_train_button3">Make Boogie</button>
            <a href="index.php" id="return_to_home">Back to home screen!</a><br /><br />
            <p id="refresh_button"></p>

            <br /><br />
            <div id="button_explanation"><b>Refresh:</b> show train model after distances have been added (Axles get in place).<br />
            <b>Make Boogie:</b> after you selected the Nr. of wheels that contain 1 boogie you press the button<br />
            after you have done that, a table will show up with the Boog Nr. and the axle Nrs. of that boogie</div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--Dit script is een test-->
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById('refresh_button').innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
</script>
```

The `$add_train = $database->train_add();` is from the form before this page. (it gets the number of axles from the inserted train.)

Comment: Apologies but what is the question?

Comment: You see the table i made in the second image?? I wan't the page to automatically create that.

Comment: That is certainly not obvious from the question, I'm afraid. Not to me anyway.